# Filter on Many to Many relationship

Tags: mysql, sql

I have 3 tables product, filter, product_filter - Many to Many relationship
I'm trying to filter products like this:

```
SELECT p.* FROM product p
INNER JOIN product_filter pf ON pf.product_id = p.id
WHERE (pf.filter_id = 1 OR pf.filter_id = 2) AND pf.filter_id = 3
```

The problem is that there are products that have all the filters(1,2,3) but i get 0 results

Please help :)

Comment: I think the OP wants where a product has a filter (1 and 3) or (2 and 3)

Answer (score 3):

For a given row in the cross product there is only one filter_id. You don't have 1 and 3 in the same row in product_filter.

To get that effect try a double join along these lines :-

```
SELECT p.* FROM product p
INNER JOIN product_filter pf1 ON pf1.product_id = p.id
INNER JOIN product_filter pf2 ON pf2.product_id = p.id
WHERE (pf1.filter_id = 1 OR pf1.filter_id = 2) AND pf2.filter_id = 3
```

Comment: BTW another option is to use DISTINCT in the WHERE condition and avoid the joins.

Comment: Hey Noam, can you add an example... i'm very curious :)